# Javascript setTimeout

Tags: javascript

Can you tell me why this works:

```
PageMethods.UpdateForcedDisposition(forcedDisposition, a.value, SucceededCallback, FailedCallback);
```

When this doesn’t?

```
setTimeout("PageMethods.UpdateForcedDisposition(" + forcedDisposition + "," + a.value + ", SucceededCallback, FailedCallback);", 1000);
```

Interestingly, a similar call works with [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout):

```
setTimeout("PageMethods.UpdateSales(" + id + ", " + a.value + ", SucceededCallback, FailedCallback);", 1000);
```

…I’m stumped!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Avoid passing a string to `setTimeout`.  Where possible, use anonymous functions:

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    PageMethods.UpdateForcedDisposition(
        forcedDisposition, 
        a.value, 
        SucceededCallback, 
        FailedCallback
    );
}, 1000);
```

A `setTimeout` with a string executes in the global scope.  If you're trying to reference variables from the current scope, you'll hit an error.