# why settimeout not delay the function execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, liferay, settimeout

```
function tryToDownload(url)
{

       oIFrm = document.getElementById('myIFrm');
       oIFrm.src = url;
      // alert(url);
      // url=escape(url);

      setTimeout(deletefile(url), 25000); 
}
```

following is deletfile function

```
function deletefile(url){

$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url: "<%= addToDoDeleteDownloadFile %>",
    data:{filename:url},
    type : "GET",
    timeout : 20000,
    dataType : "text",
    success : function(data) {
        alert("success");

    }
    });
}
```

above is my jQuery and i m calling one function at the end after 25 second,but some how it's not delaying the deletefile(url) function and execute just after.So what should be the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript setTimeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128938/javascript-settimeout)

Comment: @Fraser: That's not really a duplicate IMHO.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In this line you are calling your function and pass its *result* to [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout).

```
setTimeout(deletefile(url), 25000);
```

If you want to delay the execution, add a wrapper function:

```
setTimeout( function(){ deletefile(url); }, 25000);
```

**EDIT**

An alternative proposed by @Petah:

```
setTimeout(deletefile, 25000, url);
```

All parameters passed to `setTimeout()` after the delay, will be passed to the function at execution. So in this case, you pass the *reference*  to the function, the delay and then the parameter to the function in that order!

Note that according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) this way of passing parameters wont work in IE before IE9.

Comment: @Bhavik Kama: If you had `foo(deletefile(url))`, that would call `deletefile` right away and pass its return value into `foo`, right? So it's exactly the same with `setTimeout`, as Sirko said.

Comment: @Petah, passing additional parameters to the function does not work in Internet Explorer

Comment: @VitaliyPetrychuk, dam. Stupid IE.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are calling the function, and using the return value in the setTimeout call. Wrap it in an anonymous function so that it's called by setTimeout:

```
function tryToDownload(url) {

    oIFrm = document.getElementById('myIFrm');
    oIFrm.src = url;
   // alert(url);
   // url=escape(url);

   setTimeout(function() { deletefile(url); }, 25000);

}
```